# How to create a foreign key on Id/ParentId

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of items.

Each Item has an Id, a ParentId which is another item, and an ItemTypeId.

Now, I want to create a constraint to ensure that there every Item has a parent.

One way to do this would be to make the ParentId non-nullable. Sounds simple, but the top item of the chain has no parent, so that is not possible.

I cannot make the Root Item have a ParentId of itself, as the UI sometimes tries to do that, and it causes an orphaned item.

So the next idea is create a nullable foreign key. But I actually don't want the Foreign Key to be null unless ItemTypeId = 1.

So, how do I create that?

Comment: Root  element could refer to itself `ID = 1, ParentId = 1`. Then you could check for root using `WHERE ID = ParentId` instead of `WHERE ParentId IS NULL`

Comment: Tried that, but there is actually a constraint that an Item cannot have a Parent as itself, as sometimes the UI makes a mistake and tries to do that which results in an orphan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
    ID           INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ITEM_ID_TYPE INT NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID    INT NULL,
    CHECK ((ITEM_ID_TYPE=1 AND PARENT_ID IS NULL) OR PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TAB FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES TAB(ID)
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4818a6d98d7f9f05aec7a3f1213ca0d)**

Comment: Thanks very much. +1 for the DB. Haven't seen that before.